# Cyclic references and garbage collection in python

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I just wanted to make sure I understand https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#reference-counts right:

I have two classes that (for some purposes must have a reference to each other):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, child):
        self._child = child
        self._child.parent = self
    @property
    def child(self)
        return self._child
    @child.setter
    def child(self, value):
        #Optional to delete reference to parent
        '''
        self._child.parent = None
        '''
        self._child = value
        self._child.parent = self

class Child(object):
    @property
    def parent(self):
        return self._parent
    @parent.setter
    def parent(self, value)
        self._parent = value
```

Do I need to make the `self._child.parent = None` before setting a new child so that the old child can be garbaged? I'm pretty overwhelmed by the above linked reference and this case is something I am not sure about. Everything I found until now described the case when two elements are deleted and they have a pointer to each other.

Comment: Note that the use of a `property` here is entirely redundant and not needed. Just use `self.child` and `self.parent attributes. This is not Java where you use getters and setters as a matter of course, you can always switch to using a property later on if you need to (because you need to do additional processing when setting or getting, for example).

Comment: I know, actually there is a lot of `setter` logic when trying to set - I just skipped all these to get a clearer example.

Comment: There may be a point in adding `self._child.parent = self` in the `child.setter` property here though.

Comment: I must have accidentally removed that one while deleting the setter logic. To make it self-contained I edited the question. Thanks :-)

Comment: If you now use `self.child = child` in `__init__` you can remove the doubled `self._child.parent = self` line there and avoid repeating yourself. :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok, I messed up copying my code here. There in actual code is a difference between the init-child-setter and the child-setter itself (for init there are less restrictions on the child). But since you mention it, I could move the code around in the setter to make it less repetition :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set `self._child.parent = None` in that case, no. You already are breaking the circle by setting the parent reference to the child object to something else.

When the reference *to* the child object is gone, the circle is broken and the object can be deleted by the normal reference counting mechanisms; it doesn't matter that it itself still has *outgoing* references.

Even if there was a circular reference, the garbage collector will take care of the circle by breaking one of the references in the circle. The only situation this would be a concern is if one of the objects in the circle has a custom `__del__` method.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I was actually not sure because I tried it using a big array as child and without deleting the reference to the child the memory (ok I just watched the task manager) wasn't decreasing for a few seconds while with the deletion of the childs pointer to the parent the memory was almost immediatly freed. But that may be some just because the gc was slow because of something, because I cannot reproduce it anymore.

Comment: @MSeifert: Your OS will not reclaim freed memory immediately unless there is a pressing need for that memory elsewhere. Programs free old and allocate new memory all the time; the OS allocation of memory to a program is thus best kept stable for a while even if larger amounts of memory have just been freed.

Comment: @MSeifert: as such, watching the memory allocation in the task manager is an extremely unreliable method of watching for memory issues.

Comment: I only asked because while running the script I constantly had 100% RAM exhaustion for the run. In the second run with the `self._child.parent = None` it was only on 100% for about half the time. But maybe something else caused that. Like I said now I cannot reproduce it again. Thanks for your help